# Can't clear form input values in ngDialog template in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-dialog

I am using ngDialog [ https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog ] to create a modal, and I have a basic form which is making a POST request when I click a button. On that same button click, I want the form inputs to clear. Typically you can just do something like `$scope.valueOfNgModel = "";` but this is not working in this case. Also the ngDialog scope is the same as it's instantiating controller's $scope.

Here's the ngDialog instantiation:

```
$scope.addStudents = function() {
  ngDialog.open({
    template: 'addStudents',
    scope: $scope
  });
};
```

Here's the ngDialog Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudents">
  <h1> Add Students to Your Class </h1>

  <form ng-model="myForm" ng-submit="addNewStudent(newStudent)">
    <input ng-model="newStudent.firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input ng-model="newStudent.lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input ng-model="newStudent.email" placeholder="Email">
    <input ng-model="newStudent.image" placeholder="imageUrl">
    <h3> Note: Student Password by Default will be Firstname.lastname </h3>

    <button class="ngdialog-button 
        ngdialog-button-primary" 
        type="submit">Add Student
    </button>
</form>

</script>
```

And Here's the function that runs on the fomr submit (or button click) that I want to clear out all the input fields:

```
$scope.addNewStudent = function(student) {

  var newUserToAdd = {
    firstName: student.firstName,
    lastName: student.lastName,
    teacher: false,
    email: student.email,
    password: student.firstName + '.' + student.lastName,
    classesBelongTo: [$scope.currentClassId],
    image: student.image
  };

  userService.postNewUser(newUserToAdd)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.loggedInUser = response.data;
    })
    console.log("this is $scope.newStudent", $scope.newStudent); //this is undefined - I'm not sure why

    $scope.newStudent = {}; //I tried this to clear it out
    $scope.$apply(); //I tried this to no avail
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a name to your form, then call `$scope.yourFormName.$setPristine();`

Exemple : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charms/AhGDC/24/)